# Is there a verb to say "I'm not interested anymore?"

Tags: word-choice, verbs

What is the closest verb or phrasal verb in English to say "I'm not interested anymore"?

For example, you have been in a car dealer store, and the day after the dealer call you and give you some offers but you are not just interested in that brand anymore.

Comment: Let's not play a guessing game of "what is the language (Persian?), what is the verb".  Look up the word in a bilingual dictionary and then tell us why the translation given there is no good.

Comment: James’s request is fair. If you were unable to find anything, tell us so. Also, give us an example sentence or dialogue. Other details would be helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

You can **cool** on an offer or on an idea:

> **cool** *v.*
>
> - become or cause to become less hot
> - become or cause to become calm or less excited
>
> *“He was involved in discussions about turning the Telegraph tabloid but hinted recently that he had **cooled** on the idea.” ([The Guardian, 2004-10-27](https://www.theguardian.com/media/2004/oct/27/pressandpublishing.thedailytelegraph1))*

However it would be more common to emphasize the change: *I have **lost interest***, *I have become **less interested***.